# how to lock exposure in LG G4 using camera2 api?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am making custom camera app using camera2 api.

Locking AE used to work well, but recently I checked it on LG G4. It is not working. 
Thi is my code:
`builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);`

Android version is 5.1

Is there anyone who has done this?

Comment: I have recently run into exposure lock issues and wondering if there is any states you found your camera was in preventing you from doing this.  Did you find out what the issue was?